# How to resolve overload ambiguity in method references?

Tags: kotlin, method-reference

Say I want to assign the java method [`Log.d(String, String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to a variable `x` of method type `(String, String) -> Int` and I do it like this:

```
val x: (String, String) -> Int = android.util.Log::d
```

The compiler says:

```
Error:(50, 56) Overload resolution ambiguity:
public open fun d(tag: kotlin.String!, msg: kotlin.String!): kotlin.Int defined in android.util.Log
public open fun d(tag: kotlin.String!, msg: kotlin.String!, tr: kotlin.Throwable!): kotlin.Int defined in android.util.Log
```

Obviously there is a second method `Log.d(String, String, Throwable)` but how do I tell the compiler which one I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disambiguation here is currently unsupported (will be supported later).

As a workaround, you can use a lambda expression:

```
{ s, s1 -> android.util.Log.d(s, s1) }
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Can we expect infered disambiguation based on the variable's type (similar to Java 8)?

Comment: @cypressious, yes, sure

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: @fredoverflow In the upcoming M13 milestone this is fixed

Comment: Is M13 really coming next week?

Comment: @fredoverflow released yesterday

Comment: @user3175580 the syntax posted in OP is now supported, I'm trying with Kotlin 1.2.30

Answer (score 1):

To resolve it you have to specify the type of the variable explicitly:

```
fun foo(i: Int) = 1
fun foo(str: String) = "AAA"

fun main() {
  val fooInt: (Int) -> Int = ::foo
  println(fooInt(123)) // 1
  val fooStr: (String) -> String = ::foo
  println(fooStr("")) // AAA
}
```

case with constructors:

```
class StudentId(val value: Int)
data class UserId(val value: Int) {
   constructor(studentId: StudentId) : this(studentId.value)
}

fun main() {
   val intToUserId: (Int) -> UserId = ::UserId
   println(intToUserId(1)) // UserId(value=1)

   val studentId = StudentId(2)
   val studentIdToUserId: (StudentId) -> UserId = ::UserId
   println(studentIdToUserId(studentId)) // UserId(value=2)
}
```